# Mule: PGP decryption giving error message Invalid PGP message

Tags: encryption, mule, bouncycastle, pgp

Implementing mule pgp encryption decryption for an xml file. While decryption its raises an error

```
ERROR 2015-06-05 12:06:34,192 [Thread-8] org.mule.module.pgp.AbstractTransformPolicy: Invalid PGP message

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid PGP message
    at org.mule.module.pgp.DecryptStreamTransformer.initialize(DecryptStreamTransformer.java:79)
    at org.mule.module.pgp.TransformContinuouslyPolicy$ContinuousWork.execute(TransformContinuouslyPolicy.java:60)
    at org.mule.module.pgp.AbstractTransformPolicy$TransformerWork.run(AbstractTransformPolicy.java:109)
```

I debugged mule pgp  package and in DecryptStreamTransformer

```
public void initialize(OutputStream out) throws Exception
    {
        InputStream decodedInputStream = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(this.toBeDecrypted);
        PGPObjectFactory pgpF = new PGPObjectFactory(decodedInputStream);
        Object o = pgpF.nextObject();

        if (o == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid PGP message");
        }
```

What might be the reasons of PGPObjectFactory returning nextObject as null. Also logging message payload after flow element

```
 <decrypt-transformer name="decryptTransformer" strategy-ref="pgpEncryptionStrategy"/>
<logger level="INFO" doc:name=" Message Logger" message="#[payload]"/>
<mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer
            jaxbContext-ref="jaxb" doc:name="JAXB-Unmarshaller"
            returnClass="com.generated.Communication" />
```

Payload is displayed as
  org.mule.module.pgp.LazyTransformedInputStream@17d80e9.

How can i modify this instance to xml so that mulexml jaxb element can marshall this to required object.

Comment: Can you please show the complete flows where PGP encryption and decryption are done? I'll revisit my answer when you'll provide more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in [its source code](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/modules/xml/src/main/java/org/mule/module/xml/transformer/jaxb/JAXBUnmarshallerTransformer.java):

```
registerSourceType(DataTypeFactory.INPUT_STREAM);
```

the `jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer` accepts any input stream as a valid source, so the issue is not there.

Comment: HI David i am sending u the code for necryption and decryption please have  a look. Error message i am getting is

Comment: ERROR 2015-06-29 14:50:48,401 [Thread-17] org.mule.module.pgp.AbstractTransformPolicy: unknown object in stream: 53
java.io.IOException: unknown object in stream: 53
 at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPObjectFactory.nextObject(Unknown Source)
 at org.mule.module.pgp.DecryptStreamTransformer.initialize(DecryptStreamTransformer.java:91)
 at org.mule.module.pgp.TransformContinuouslyPolicy$ContinuousWork.execute(TransformContinuouslyPolicy.java:60)
 at org.mule.module.pgp.AbstractTransformPolicy$TransformerWork.run(AbstractTransformPolicy.java:109)

Comment: Hi David a sper your suggestion i have tested the code by replacing AMQP connector with file connector and the code is working. How can i make it work now with AMQP connector as inbound and outbound messages are in my case is from RabbitMQ queues

Comment: Its working with AMQP connector in same flow(encryption and decryption both in same flow).

Comment: Thanks david your comments helped me to debug and identify problem with the code. Problem was with for-each scope and not with encryption/decryption code.